# How to better structure my classes and properties?

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I am trying to programme a board game using python and object orientated programming. However, the structure of my classes and properties seems a bit tortuous even if I have made it do what I want. It doesn't seem very elegant and I'm sure it will lead to things getting too complicated and making the code hard to follow as I progress. I will try to give a simplified example of how I've structured things:

```
class GameState:
    def __init__(self, n_players):
        self.n_players = n_players
        self.players = []
        for player in range(self.n_players):
            self.players.append(Player(player))
        // other properties

    // other functions

class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.building = Building()
        self.workers = 3
        // other properties

class Building:

    def __init__(self):
        self.worker = False

    def action(self, player):
        if self.worker == True:
            player.workers += 1
```

But now if I want a player to use the building action I have to do something like the below. It feels like I should be able to structure things better to avoid having to pass an instance of a Player class to the Building action function.

```
game = GameState(4)
game.players[0].building.action(game.players[0])
```

The idea is that each player will have an instance of the Building class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to suggest alternatives without knowing the exact format of your game. If each building is only ever associated with a single player at a time, I'd add that to the initialisation and reference it directly.

```
class Building:
    def __init__(self, player):
        self.worker = False
        self.player = player

    def action(self):
        if self.worker == True:
            self.player.workers += 1
```

Alternatively, if each player will only ever have one building associated with them, then the action function should probably be in the player class rather than the building.